# Implementation of JAXB-API not found for SOAP web service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, soap, spring-ws, webservice-client

I'm trying to connect to a SOAP web service using a Spring Boot project. I can generate classes from the wsdl and I can confirm that the generated classes end up in the target folder. However, I can't run the project.

What am I missing here? Some dependency I guess? I've included everything I can think of at this point.

Also if there are alternative ways of consuming soap web services that entirely avoid this dependency mess, that would also be appreciated.'

This is what happens when I try to run the project.

```
java -version
openjdk version "15.0.2" 2021-01-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 15.0.2+7)

./mvnw clean && ./mvnw jaxb2:generate
BUILD SUCCESS

 ./mvnw spring-boot:run
Application run failed
Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory
```

And here's my pom file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>api</name>
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.4.21</kotlin.version>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
            <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.stripe</groupId>
            <artifactId>stripe-java</artifactId>
            <version>20.36.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- I included everything I could think of here... -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.14.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                    <generatePackage>PACKAGE</generatePackage>
                    <schemas>
                        <schema>
                            <url>URL</url>
                        </schema>
                    </schemas>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

---

Edit:

Removing all dependencies related to jax except for `spring-boot-starter-web-services` result in the same error.

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory
```

Comment: You have multiple JAXb implementations/versions on your classpath. Use one.

Comment: What do you mean precisely? E.g. jaxb-impl is only added once.

Comment: and `jaxb-core` and `jaxb-runtime` all of which contain more or less of jaxb. Depending on which is loaded first class may or may not be available. As mentioned use 1 not 2 or 3. There is also a version mismatch (2.3.1 for the API and 3.0.0 for the implementation) keep the versions the same.

Comment: I can actually remove all dependencies related to jax except "spring-boot-starter-web-services" and still generate the classes. But the issue with running still remains. There is still a dependency missing apparently.

Comment: You will need jaxb as a dependency else it won't be included.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!